# Proving a possible corollary of the monotone convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of nonnegative measurable functions on $E$ that converges point wise on $E$ to $f$. Suppose $f_n \leq f$ for each $n$. Show that:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_E f_n = \int_E f.$$

So, I've already proved the monotone convergence theorem, the assumption of which is the same as what I'm trying to prove except for in the monotone convergence theorem the sequences of functions is increasing. I feel like there must be some clever trick to use the convergence theorem to prove this one... I've been thinking about it for awhile but I fear I'm stuck in tunnel vision. Insights appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: Is this not just the dominated convergence theorem? Or are you not assuming that $f$ is integrable?

Comment: @Math1000 the functions are assumed to be measurable,not necessarily integrable.

Comment: @MariosGretsas Indeed, hence the edit to my comment. But since the functions are assumed to be nonnegative, the only pathological case that comes to mind is when $\int_E f=+\infty$.

Comment: Maybe $f$ is infinite on a set of positive measure ,so you cannot use D.C.T

Comment: Fatou's lemma gives $\int f \leq \liminf \int f_n.$ By assumption, $\limsup \int f_n \leq \int f.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowed to use Fatou's lemma$^{(1)}$, then
$$\int f = \int \liminf f_n \leq \liminf \int f_n \leq \int f,$$
where the middle inequality is Fatou's lemma. This implies that $\liminf \int f_n=\int f$. It is obvious that $\limsup \int f_n \leq \int f$. Since the $\limsup$  is bigger than the $\liminf$, it is also equal to $\int f$, and it follows that $\lim \int f_n=\int f.$

$^{(1)}$ Using Fatou's lemma is not a big deal, since it is just the monotone convergence theorem applied to $g_i:=\inf\{f_i,f_{i+1},\cdots\}$.

Comment: does $\liminf \int f_n \leq \int f$ hold because $f_n \leq f$ for all $n$?

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom Yes. Since $f_n \leq f$ for all $n$, we have that $\int f_n \leq \int f$ for all $n$, and then $\liminf \int f_n \leq \int f$.